# Skipping Active Record breaks Rails Generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-generate, rails-generators, ruby-2.3

I created a new Rails project with the `-O --api` flags turned on, and `rails g model` is now broken for me: it does nothing and simply says "running via Spring preloader" (its not a Spring bug as I've tried removing Spring) and returns.

After that, I created a new project (exactly the same, just without `-O`), and `rails g model` worked fine. Is it that skipping AR breaks generators? If so, how shall I avoid?

I'm using Ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 5.0.0.1 on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS.

Comment: `rails g model` will create an ActiveRecord model by default - but you've disabled ActiveRecord. What's the behaviour you're expecting instead? Are you using a different ORM that you expect to be invoked at this point?

Comment: I got it. I'm using Google Cloud Datastore, which is not a ORM, with this Rails app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rails g model` is only useful for ActiveRecord models (by default) or other model types that have an integrated generator. You can invoke the latter by using the `-o` flag when running `rails g model`.

However, there [might not be such an integration for Google Cloud Datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/617), so I think you're going to have to manage your models manually.